# Проблема с MVC-приложением после клонирования из репозитория

Tags: c#, git, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc

Создал MVC-приложение, поместил его на github. В какой-то момент понадобилась его копия, клонировал проект из репозитория. После данных действий не видит некоторые классы: интерфейсы из другого сопряженного проекта, различные MVC-компоненты, например: controller, от которого наследуются все кастомные контроллеры, ScriptBundle, ActionResult. Однако, это не мешает приложению работать корректно, без вылетов.
Пробовал чистить проект через Clean solution, вручную удалять все файлы из папки bin, результата нет.
[image: Пример описанной выше ситуации]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался очень странным и совершенно не очевидным: после добавления нового контроллера в проект через add --> controller, в котором уже адекватно отображались MVC-компоненты, так же адекватно стали отображаться и остальные компоненты, с которыми были проблемы.